# How to store a nested dict in a local file and retrieve it back maintaining the data type as dict and not str

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I saved a list which contains nested dict to a csv file. When I tried to retrieve back the dict, it's type is being converted to str. How do I get back the dict type?

This is the list:

```
a = [{'Ford India Pvt Ltd': {'x': ['June, 18',
    'July, 18',
    'Aug, 18',
    'Sep, 18',
    'Oct, 18',
    'Nov, 18',
    'Jan, 19'],
   'y': array([3864., 3305., 3104., 3959., 4522., 3218., 3190.]),
   'name': 'Passenger Cars'}}]
```

I have tried the following code -

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval(a)
```

I am getting:

> ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x1c2788d828>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe save it as a json file instead with print(json.dump(a),file=file_pointer) and a=json.load(file_pointer), that appears to be easier than transforming it to csv.

Of course than you can't save some datatypes in the list/dict like function pointers or tuples.

Comment: You can't serialize `np.array` as JSON